# Laravel: How can I convert this query back to eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I convert this query back to eloquent. I made this for my testing because I can't get the result on my original laravel query so I tried testing directly to database. Now my problem is I wrapped my query in select and group 
 to get what result I needed

```
SELECT t.restaurant_number, COUNT(t.lowDollarModified)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        header.transaction_id,
        header.restaurant_number,
        (SUM(CASE
            WHEN
                 (
                    header.net_amount <= 2.50 or
                    details.detail_type = 90
                    or details.modifier_flag > 0
                )
                AND tender.description = '01 CASH'
            THEN
                1
            ELSE 0
        END)) AS lowDollarModified
    FROM
        `db_prod`.`header`
            INNER JOIN
        `db_prod`.`details` ON `header`.`transaction_id` = `details`.`transaction_id`
            INNER JOIN
        `db_prod`.`tender` ON `header`.`transaction_id` = `tender`.`transaction_id`
    WHERE
        `business_date` BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-04'
            AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
                *
            FROM
                `db_prod`.`ticket_mapping`
            WHERE
                `header`.`transaction_id` = `ticket_mapping`.`transaction_id`
                    AND `isClosed` = 1)
            AND `header`.`restaurant_number` = 1606
    GROUP BY `header`.`restaurant_number`, transaction_id
    Having lowDollarModified > 0
) as t
GROUP BY t.restaurant_number
```

Here is my original query in laravel

```
$stores1 = Header::select([
                DB::raw('header.transaction_id'),
                DB::raw('header.restaurant_number'),
                DB::raw('(SUM(CASE WHEN 
                                (   
                                    header.net_amount <= '.$void.' or
                                    details.detail_type = 90 or 
                                    details.modifier_flag > 0
                                ) and
                                tender.description = "01 CASH" 
                                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                            ) ) as lowDollarModified
                        ')
            ])
            ->join('details', 'header.transaction_id','details.transaction_id')
            ->join('tender','header.transaction_id','tender.transaction_id')
            ->whereBetween('business_date',[$date_from, $date_to])
            ->whereDoesntHave('ticketmapping', function($query){
                $query->where('isClosed', 1);
            })
            ->where('header.restaurant_number','1606')
            ->groupBy('header.restaurant_number', 'header.transaction_id')
            ->havingRaw('lowDollarModified > 0')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the raw query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB::select(`t.restaurant_number`)
        ->addSelect(DB::raw(`COUNT(t.lowDollarModified)`))
        ->from(`SELECT header.transaction_id, header.restaurant_number, ( SUM( CASE WHEN ( header.net_amount <= 2.50 or details.detail_type = 90 or details.modifier_flag > 0 ) AND tender.description = 01 CASH THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) ) AS lowDollarModified FROM db_prod.header INNER JOIN db_prod.details ON header.transaction_id = details.transaction_id INNER JOIN db_prod.tender ON header.transaction_id = tender.transaction_id WHERE business_date BETWEEN 2018-03-01 AND 2018-03-04 AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM db_prod.ticket_mapping WHERE header.transaction_id = ticket_mapping.transaction_id AND isClosed = 1 ) AND header.restaurant_number = 1606 GROUP BY header.restaurant_number, transaction_id Having lowDollarModified > 0 as t`)
        ->groupBy(`t.restaurant_number`)
        ->get();
```

This was generated by this tool: http://www.midnightcowboycoder.com/

Answer (score 0):

For advance query but doesn't need any loop within that stored proc will be your last resort. You can do a `VIEW TABLE` then create a model for that. Instead of doing a `'whereRaw'` in your code.